# How to remove space when combining multiple excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hy guys,
In my scenario I used 3 functions to get the surname , the first initial of the family name and a number from a string of numbers so that in the end I would get an email address like johnd90@gmail.com

```
      Name and Family Name    Number
      B                       C

 2   John Doe                1750915122425
```

I managed to write this formula

```
=LOWER(LEFT(B2;SEARCH(" ";B2))&LOWER(MID(B2;FIND(" ";B2)+1;1))&MID($C2;COLUMN()-3;2)&"@gmail.com")
```

The problem is that I get the desired result only with a small space between the first name and initial

```
john d75@gmail.com instead of johnd75@gmail.com
```

How can I remove that space?

Comment: `LEFT(B2;SEARCH(" ";B2))` gets the left part of the string up to and including the first space.  Add a `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `SUBSTITUTE` the spaces with nothing:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(LEFT(B2;SEARCH(" ";B2))&LOWER(MID(B2;FIND(" ";B2)+1;1))&MID($C2;COLUMN()-3;2)&"@gmail.com")," ","")
```